# C++11 support for higher-order list functions

Tags: c++, functional-programming, c++11, lambda, list

Most functional programming languages (e.g. Common Lisp, Scheme / Racket, Clojure, Haskell, Scala, Ocaml, SML) support some common higher-order functions on lists, such as `map`, `filter`, `takeWhile`, `dropWhile`, `foldl`, `foldr` (see e.g. [Common Lisp, Scheme / Racket, Clojure side-by-side reference sheet](http://hyperpolyglot.org/lisp), the [Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.1/Data-List.html), [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html), [OCaml](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/List.html), and the [SML](http://www.standardml.org/Basis/list.html) documentation.)

Does C++11 have equivalent standard methods or functions on lists? For example, consider the following Haskell snippet:

```hs
let xs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
let ys = map (\x -> x * x) xs
```

How can I express the second expression in modern standard C++?

```
std::list<int> xs = ... // Initialize the list in some way.
std::list<int> ys = ??? // How to translate the Haskell expression?
```

What about the other higher-order functions mentioned above?
Can they be directly expressed in C++?

Comment: Yes, but they operate on more general concepts than that specific implementation of a doubly linked list. As do Python's operations in this area. I much prefer that to being tied to a specific data structure. Ever tried to do these operations on, say, a `Data.Sequence` in Haskell? It's comparatively ugly.

Comment: "It's comparatively ugly.": Compared to what?

Comment: Compared to the same operation on `[a]`. You either have to hide the prelude function, hack around prelude, or choose a different and less intuitive name.

Comment: Maybe you are right, but the topic of this question is how to express common list higher-order functions in C++, not how to implement analogous functions on Data.Sequence in Haskell.

Comment: I know. My point is that you *don't* want those operations implemented for lists specifically, not in C++ and not anywhere else. That's far too restrictive.

Comment: Well if there is a more general implementation it can certainly be applied to the specific case of lists. In general, I am interested on how to transform a sequence of values into a new sequence of values by applying a transformation or a filter on its elements, or reducing the sequence to a single value by repeatedly applying a binary operation on its values. The actual data structure that is used to implement this is not so important. I just need an easy, idiomatic way to implement it (other than writing my own ad-hoc loop).

Comment: @delnan I would argue that Haskell is much more *general* in its approach. `Functor`, `Foldable`, and `Traversable` achieve this in as abstract a way as I can think. `Data.Sequence` is an instance of all of these, so you can just do `fmap (\x -> x * x) xs`. `map` is `fmap` specialized for beginners.

Comment: Because of lazy evalution, haskell's lists are streams...  And yeah modern haskell uses <$>(fmap) for all map-ables, traverse for all Traversables, and fold for all Foldables.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Even more, C++ have such functions, take a look to [algorithm](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/) (or [with C++11 additions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm)) header:

```
std::transform
std::for_each
std::remove_copy_if
```

They can be easily used with any container.

For example your code can be expressed like this (with C++11 lambdas for easy coding):

```
std::vector<int> x = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
std::vector<int> y;
std::transform(x.begin(), x.end(), std::back_inserter(y), [](int elem){ return elem * elem; });
```

Less intuitive, but you can easily wrap the `std::transform` call into function which would return new container (with `move` semantics for better perfomance).

Comment: Thanks. I'd like to simplify some code I wrote a few days ago and this could really help make it much shorter. Just one small question: why do you need to pass x.begin() and x.end()? Wouldn't be sufficient to just pass the vector x?

Comment: `std::transform` takes two iterators, so, you can take a slice of a  container (remember that you have iterators arithmetics).

Comment: So you have two operations in one: taking a slice, and applying a transformation.

Comment: Formerly you have two iterators and applying transform to elements between them. Iterators not a common in functional programming.

Comment: +1: Thanks for the links. I think I can find all the relevant information there.

Comment: For `map` correspondance is mostly `transform` and `for_each`, the second one make in-place transform (without new container). `filter` is `copy_if` and other `*copy*`. `takeWhile`, `dropWhile` can be done with iterators arithmetics. `foldl` and `foldr` is a `accumulate`.

Comment: "Iterators not a common in functional programming.": Is there a C++ solution that does not use iterators? I can program one myself but I wanted to know if there is a standard one before I start reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @Giorgio: And what do you want? In functional programming most things being done using not iteration, but a recursion. You can look into the [LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232222/is-there-a-linq-library-for-c) libraries or into [boost.iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/iterator/doc/index.html).

Comment: E.g. something like: `list.map(<my function>)` which returns a new list object.

Comment: I haven't met such libraries, in C++ the iterator-based algorithm much useful. You can make a wrapper of, in your case, `std::transform` like: `Y<U> map(T<U>, std::function<Y(U)>)`.